# XML select and update

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:EligibilityRequest xmlns:ns1="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/mmiscommon" xmlns:ns4="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligrequest" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.eohhs.ma.gov/newMMIS/ws/2006/05/MemberInfo" xmlns:ns5="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligresponse">
    <ns4:transactionsource id_source="HIX" id_other="00000004353" id_medicaid="100208425271"/>
    <ns4:demographic cde_born_to_st_empl=" " cde_born_to_ma=" " ind_pregnancy=" " pct_income_fpl="125" amt_income_fpl="1556.57" amt_indv_income="1638.5" amt_indv_prem="0" mail_adr_zip_code="02532" mail_adr_state="MA" mail_adr_city="Boston" mail_adr_street_2="APT 56" mail_adr_street_1="112 Main ST" res_adr_zip_code="02532" res_adr_state="MA" res_adr_city="Boston" res_adr_street_2="APT 56" res_adr_street_1="112 Main ST" nam_first="John" nam_last="Father" email="MAMedicaid01@hcentive.com" num_phone_day="8575550056" cde_lang_written="RUSSIN" cde_primary_lang="RUSSIN" cde_disability_stat=" " cde_homeless="N" cde_ethnicity="UNKNOW" cde_race="UNKNOW" cde_citizen="C" num_primary_ssn="278938115" cde_sex="M" dte_birth="1978-09-09"/>
    <ns4:case amt_family_prem_assist="0" amt_family_mh_prem="0" amt_family_prem="0" hoh_nam_last="Father" hoh_nam_first="John" cde_case_status="2" num_case="00003235C"/>
    <ns4:eligibility cde_office="555" cde_region="58" dte_appl="2014-11-13" family_size="2" amt_gross_income="1556.57" cde_cat="D1" cde_elig_status="4" cde_line="00" dte_end_elig="2014-11-13" dte_begin_elig="2014-11-03"/>
    <ns4:eligibility cde_open_reason="01" cde_office="555" cde_region="58" dte_appl="2014-11-13" family_size="2" amt_gross_income="1556.57" cde_cat="D1" cde_elig_status="1" cde_line="00" dte_begin_elig="2014-11-03"/>
</ns4:EligibilityRequest>
```

If you open this attached XML, you can see there is 2 tags of <`ns4:eligibility`

I have to first select this last sub string, either by regexp_substr or simple str .. means output should be:

```
<ns4:eligibility cde_open_reason="01" cde_office="555" cde_region="58" dte_appl="2014-11-13" family_size="2" amt_gross_income="1556.57" cde_cat="D1" cde_elig_status="1" cde_line="00" dte_begin_elig="2014-11-03"/>
```

Then append this string to another xml. same like this. just append in last.

Comment: Please include the XML.

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE XML_IN ( id INT, xml CLOB );
INSERT INTO XML_IN VALUES ( 1, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:EligibilityRequest xmlns:ns1="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/mmiscommon" xmlns:ns4="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligrequest" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.eohhs.ma.gov/newMMIS/ws/2006/05/MemberInfo" xmlns:ns5="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligresponse">
    <ns4:transactionsource id_source="HIX" id_other="00000004353" id_medicaid="100208425271"/>
    <ns4:demographic cde_born_to_st_empl=" " cde_born_to_ma=" " ind_pregnancy=" " pct_income_fpl="125" amt_income_fpl="1556.57" amt_indv_income="1638.5" amt_indv_prem="0" mail_adr_zip_code="02532" mail_adr_state="MA" mail_adr_city="Boston" mail_adr_street_2="APT 56" mail_adr_street_1="112 Main ST" res_adr_zip_code="02532" res_adr_state="MA" res_adr_city="Boston" res_adr_street_2="APT 56" res_adr_street_1="112 Main ST" nam_first="John" nam_last="Father" email="MAMedicaid01@hcentive.com" num_phone_day="8575550056" cde_lang_written="RUSSIN" cde_primary_lang="RUSSIN" cde_disability_stat=" " cde_homeless="N" cde_ethnicity="UNKNOW" cde_race="UNKNOW" cde_citizen="C" num_primary_ssn="278938115" cde_sex="M" dte_birth="1978-09-09"/>
    <ns4:case amt_family_prem_assist="0" amt_family_mh_prem="0" amt_family_prem="0" hoh_nam_last="Father" hoh_nam_first="John" cde_case_status="2" num_case="00003235C"/>
    <ns4:eligibility cde_office="555" cde_region="58" dte_appl="2014-11-13" family_size="2" amt_gross_income="1556.57" cde_cat="D1" cde_elig_status="4" cde_line="00" dte_end_elig="2014-11-13" dte_begin_elig="2014-11-03"/>
    <ns4:eligibility cde_open_reason="01" cde_office="555" cde_region="58" dte_appl="2014-11-13" family_size="2" amt_gross_income="1556.57" cde_cat="D1" cde_elig_status="1" cde_line="00" dte_begin_elig="2014-11-03"/>
</ns4:EligibilityRequest>');

CREATE TABLE XML_OUT( id INT, xml CLOB );
INSERT INTO XML_OUT VALUES ( 1, '<test><attribute>existing</attribute></test>' );
```

**Query**:

```
MERGE INTO XML_OUT o
USING XML_IN i ON ( o.id = i.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
  SET xml =  APPENDCHILDXML(
                XMLType( o.xml ),
                '/test',
                EXTRACT(
                  XMLType( i.xml ),
                  '//ns4:EligibilityRequest/ns4:eligibility[last()]',
                  'xmlns:ns4="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligrequest"'
                )
              ).getClobVal();
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM XML_OUT;

        ID XML
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 <test><attribute>existing</attribute><ns4:eligibility xmlns:ns4="http:
           //newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligrequest" cde_ope
           n_reason="01" cde_office="555" cde_region="58" dte_appl="2014-11-13" fa
           mily_size="2" amt_gross_income="1556.57" cde_cat="D1" cde_elig_status="
           1" cde_line="00" dte_begin_elig="2014-11-03"/></test>
```